# install python-pdfkit can't find in channel

Tags: conda, channel, pdfkit

I'm trying to install pdfkit using conda.

Tried:

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-pdfkit
```

and:

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-pdfkit
```

also:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install python-pdfkit
```

Every time it's telling me that's it not available on my current channels.

Although when I use: conda search python-pdfkit --channel conda-forge it seems to find it.

Comment: What is your architecture? Although [`python-pdfkit` is technically tagged as `noarch`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python-pdfkit), it depends on `wkhtmltopdf`, which is [only available for **linux-64** architecture on the conda-forge channel](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/wkhtmltopdf/files).

Comment: windows-64. That would explain why I've been struggling with this.

Comment: Exactly the same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

While [`python-pdfkit` is technically tagged as **noarch**](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python-pdfkit) (i.e., architecture agnostic) in the conda-forge repository, it has a dependency on wkhtmltopdf, which [only has **linux-64** architecture support on conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/wkhtmltopdf/files).

If you're not on a **linux-64** architecture, then perhaps [try installing `wkhtmltopdf` first](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/).  Or, if you'd really like to pay it forward for others, consider [updating the feedstock for wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/conda-forge/wkhtmltopdf-feedstock#updating-wkhtmltopdf-feedstock) by adding support for your architecture to it.

Comment: I would like to take you up on this "updating the feedstock for wkhtmltopdff" to add support for Windows.  I have not programmed in C in a long time, though last year I compiled a C program just to see if I could still do it.  I program in Python all the time.  I need a PDF generator and the Python packages I am trying to install seem to require this one.  If you could provide me some pointers to update this feedback.  I have already forked the repo.  Thank you.

Comment: @RichLysakowskiPhD feel free to tag me on a PR (mfansler). I’m not so strong on Windows compilation, but happy to help where possible.